# Converting Boolean value to No or Yes from array result angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array in the below format

```html
{
  "Tasks": [
    {
      "TaskID": 303691,
      "TaskName": "Test1",
      "TaskType": "Internal",
      "Status": "Processing",
      "IsApproved": false,
      "RowNumber": 1
    },
    {
      "TaskID": 303694,
      "TaskName": "Test2",
      "TaskType": "External",
      "Status": "Processing",
      "IsApproved": true,
      "RowNumber": 2
    },
    {
      "TaskID": 303708,
      "TaskName": "Test3",
      "TaskType": "Internal",
      "Status": "Error",
      "IsApproved": false,
      "RowNumber": 3
    }
  ],
  "TotalRows": 3
}
```

I have to format the array(TaskDetail["TotalRows"]) before displaying it  by converting  "IsApproved": to 'No' or 'Yes' : based on false or true.

I am getting the array details like below

```js
getTaskList(parentId: number, userName: string) {       
        this.url = `api/${userName}/tasks/${parentId}`;
        this.taskSubscription =
            this.http.post(this.url)
            .pipe(map(o => o as TaskDetail[]))
            .subscribe((taskDetail: TaskDetail[]) => {
                this.userTasks$.next(TaskDetail["TotalRows"];
                );
                },
                    error => {
                        this.userTasks$.next(null);
                        this.errorHandlerService.handleError(error);
                    });
    }
```

So the final array will be like follows

```html
{
  "Tasks": [
    {
      "TaskID": 303691,
      "TaskName": "Test1",
      "TaskType": "Internal",
      "Status": "Processing",
      "IsApproved": No,
      "RowNumber": 1
    },
    {
      "TaskID": 303694,
      "TaskName": "Test2",
      "TaskType": "External",
      "Status": "Processing",
      "IsApproved": Yes,
      "RowNumber": 2
    },
    {
      "TaskID": 303708,
      "TaskName": "Test3",
      "TaskType": "Internal",
      "Status": "Error",
      "IsApproved": No,
      "RowNumber": 3
    }
  ],
  "TotalRows": 3
}
```

Can any one help me how to do that?

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array.

Comment: Do the opposite of this question's answers: [Using map, how do I transform a yes and no string in an objects property into a boolean true and false value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231987/using-map-how-do-i-transform-a-yes-and-no-string-in-an-objects-property-into-a)

Comment: BTW: Use strings here as "IsApproved": No, is not valid (should be "IsApproved": "No")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this, I like to create a new field and give it "_F" - for example, IsApproved_F. So I still have original value if needed. You don't need to do this if you don't like it.
Then as suggested here [Using map, how do I transform a yes and no string in an objects property into a boolean true and false value in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231987/using-map-how-do-i-transform-a-yes-and-no-string-in-an-objects-property-into-a) and as already pointed out in the comments use a map. You can also use the for loop.

```
let i = yourObject.Tasks.map(function(task){
     task.IsApproved? task.IsApproved = "Yes": task.IsApproved= "No";
     return task;
});
```